# RAND() used in SQL trigger to get random number. What happens if it generates already used number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a system where I need to generate a six digit code for every user that signs up. So I'm using this statement (SELECT LEFT(CAST(RAND()*1000000000+999999 AS INT),6) for generating it. I have made that particular row UNIQUE. The thing is that this is all happening through a trigger. My question is, What happens if the number generated by this RAND() is already in use? Will the trigger be executed again as that particular is UNIQUE? or Do I need to write any condition in the trigger itself? If I need to write any condition, Please help me with it.

Comment: *What happens if the number generated by this RAND() is already in use?* Unique constraint violation error or warning. *Will the trigger be executed again as that particular is UNIQUE?* No. *Do I need to write any condition in the trigger itself?* That's you who must decide this.

Comment: Hi Kasindi, this is a bit of an odd architectural question. A 6 digit short code might not need to be unique. @Akina is right that this will throw an error, but the shortcode shouldn't need to be random unique, assuming it is something only used on signup. Consider why you would want to store the digit for reuse, and what benefit you would have to keeping it long term.

Comment: ok, some help: 1) [Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)   2) [CREATE TRIGGER statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)   3) [MySQL 8.0 FAQ: Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-triggers.html).     After reading this, please ask a more detailed question.

Comment: @AaronMorefield *this will throw an error* Error for `INSERT`, warning for `INSERT IGNORE`, alternative flow for `INSERT .. ODKU`  and `REPLACE`.

Comment: @Aaron It's their referral code and it should be random unique for every user that signs up.

Answer (score 2):

If the randomizer generates a value that has already been used, and stores it in a column that has a UNIQUE constraint, then the row will violate the constraint, and the INSERT and any other data changed by the trigger will be cancelled.

The trigger will not retry. A retry would need to be executed by your application code, after catching the error.

It would be far simpler to use a table's auto-increment mechanism to guarantee that values are not reused.

Answer (score 1):

An example. **Use with caution!!!**

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_generate_pin
BEFORE INSERT
ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
REPEAT
    SET NEW.pin = CEIL(255 * RAND());  -- 255 is MAXVALUE for TINYINT UNSIGNED
    SET NEW.iterations = NEW.iterations + 1;
UNTIL NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM test
                   WHERE pin = NEW.pin ) END REPEAT;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11c263a2eb07b8db133ae13a3d22e549

---

This code is relatively safe - it counts the amount of iterations, and if it reaches 256 the insertion will fail. But on real system, without such counting and with more wide datatype, the code may cause server hang because of too long, infinite-like, loop. So add maximal iterations amount checking - query fail is better than server hang.